# How do I convert a WinXPx32 VHD Gen 1 VM image from a guest image to a normal host installation?

Tags: windows-xp, virtual-machine, hyper-v, vmware-workstation, microsoft-virtual-pc

How do I convert a WinXPx32 VHD Gen 1 VM image from a guest image to a normal host installation?

I want to take a virtual WinXPx32 and convert it into the Windows that boots when I turn the physical PC on.

I am not trying to install WinXP from scratch, I need to use this specific image of WinXPx32 because there is an application installed inside of it that is impossible to install from scratch.

Side comment, I am not going to connect XP to the internet.

Comment: In order to avoid wasting time for nothing check about compatibility before anything else. And bare metal installations can, under strict conditions and not without a lot of caveats, be "converted" to VMs. The other way around not so much. And using XP online in 2022, even in a VM, is asking for trouble.

Comment: I agree, I was never going to connect XP to the internet. I'm sure you meant that for the worst 1% of technicians out there.